# One project with multiple views

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework-2.0

In my play project I am linking all of my javascript and css in my main.scala.html. I also want to have a mobile interface for my application using something like JQuery mobile. Is it possible to have multiple views for one project? Can I just create a similar wrapper to main and use it for the mobile css/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want, Play! views are pretty flexible.

Event if I am not sure to fully understand what you want, I can suggest you a few things.

**Load scripts from view**

You can load specific scripts for a view into your `main.scala.html`.

`main.scala.html`

```
@(title: String, scripts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")'>
        @* By default, nothing but you can override from any view *@
        @scripts
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

`anyview.scala.html`

```
@(title: String)

@* Declare the script(s) you need for that view *@
@scripts = {
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/my-specific-script.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
}

@main(title, scripts) {
    @* Some content *@
}
```

If you do not need extra script in a view, just do not pass the `scripts` parameter (it has a default empty value in `main.scala.html`).

**Load what you need from `main.scala.html`**

By passing parameters (based on your device detection).

`main.scala.html`

```
@if(someParameter.isMobileDevice()) {
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/my-mobile-script.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

**And what about a responsive design?**

Your style can be adapted depending on the device used to view the page. You may not need to load extra things.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is ... just to check :) anyway, yes, you can have as many `layouts` as you need, there's no limit. (according to the [docs terminology](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplateUseCases), `layout` is a view which is some kind of wrapper for other views - for an example default `main.scala.html` file).

To keep the order I used to always move the `main.scala.html` layout into the new created package: `app.views._layouts`. Also I'm creating there other ones... so in your views you can just easily use:

```
@_layouts.main(params){
   ...
}
```

or

```
@_layouts.mobile(params){
   ...
}
```

**P.S.**: as Alban wrote, there is also possible to use one layout and *push* to them additional scripts. With combination of both techniques, you can do probably everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

### My2c

My best guess for such use case would be to use the right tool.
Actually, what you really want is your application to be **responsive** to the way it is used.
That is, you want responsivness. So hype isn't it ;-).

Moreover it'll be rather hard to handle, on the server side, the case where the window has been reduced... simply, because they're purely client side actions :-/ . So the viewport is 320px wide on a 1200px (real) screen.

However, you could indeed use specific parameters passed to your layouts to adapt their behaviors but it'll require you guy to manage the cases on the server side using the information your browser provides...

---

### So why not just asking the browser to do everything for you?

**Hopefully**, stable libraries will help a lot, for instance:
[**yepnopejs**](http://yepnopejs.com/) which will let you define which js files to load regarding a predicate (like `320 < screen.width`).

Or to reduce your **duplicate** code or **if-then-else** between devices, you can use yesnope along with [**responsejs**](http://responsejs.com/) that will give you the opportunity to declare some "responsive" behavior declaratively (what no JS KoOl huh?) like that:

```
<a 
   href=hi-fi.png
   data-min-width-320='<img src=lo-fi.png alt="image @ 320+">' 
   data-min-width-961='<img src=hi-fi.png alt="image @ 961+">'
> 
   text-only link @ <320px and no-js
</a>
```

---

### Or

Indeed both @biesior and @Alban answers are correct and helpful. My final touch would be to use an **implicit parameter** computed once in a [composite](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaActionsComposition) controller that extract the information from the request headers (at least).